# How to prevent vis.js timeline "customTime" item move?

Tags: javascript, css, timeline, vis.js

I coded timeline via vis.js.
And I appended custom time item using by addCustomTime().

My situation is.

I want add fixed custom time, but It move when I drag it.
Anbybody know how to prevent custom item move?

```js
  // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

  // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
  ]);

  // Configuration for the Timeline
  var options = {};

  // Create a Timeline
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
  
  timeline.addCustomTime('2013-04-21'); // I want this item not moving.
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>

<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dapriett said in [this comment](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1296#issuecomment-180023600) in the GitHub issue that @lv0gun9 linked, you can do this instead:

```
timeline.addCustomTime(date, id)
timeline.customTimes[timeline.customTimes.length - 1].hammer.off("panstart panmove panend");
```

This disables the move events on the custom time element. With @lv0gun9's css solution you'll also disable the tooltip that tells you the element's precise date when hovering on it.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1296

I added this code to css.

```
.vis-custom-time {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also disables the fact that if you hover on it with the mouse for a second it will show a tooltip telling you the exact date it was placed at.